# Reboot while repartitioning HDD left me with corrupt files

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, partition-recovery

I'm trying to get used to the feeling that I might never be able to recover my lost files. Meanwhile, I'll try to explain the situation, hoping that someone might suggest a solution:

My HDD is made up of two NTFS partitions: one primary with Windows 7 x64 on it, and a secondary used as storage for files. I no longer needed an OS on that drive, so I booted up Parted Magic OS, and deleted the primary partition. But after that, while exapanding the secondary to fill the unallocated space (moving the start point), my laptop powered off by itself! Damn!

Now, after booting in Parted Magic again, I opened my HDD and saw that some of the files were still there, but most of them were corrupt and some directories empty. However, it was showing that there were 200 gigs ot files, which was exactly how much data I had in the beginning. This single fact is keeping me hope that there might be a chance to recover my corrupted files.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Rule #1: BACK UP THE CORRUPTED DATA before running any tool to try and "fix" the partition.

Comment: You should really do what DarthAndroid suggests, this way you could at least go back if some automated tools makes situation worser.

Comment: Rule #0: BACK UP THE HARD DRIVE BEFORE REPARTITIONING--

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to recover the files using [Partition Find & Mount](http://findandmount.com/). It helped me a couple of times. There's a free version you can try out before paying for a faster commercial version. Depending on how many files and much time you have the slower free version might be good enough.

Also, to really make use of it, you'll need someplace to store the recovered partition(s) and files -- it doesn't fix a corrupted drive / partitioning scheme, only allows to you mount "virtual" drives that you can then copy to another location (like an external or network drive share).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that!

I actually had to use GetDataBack (as friend suggested), because I didn't have enough free space on any other drive to store everything. Anyway it worked flawlessly.

Comment: GetDataBack sounds very similar to Partition Find & Mount, so it seems like both would require the same amount of space on another drive -- so it not really clear why you preferred it. Regardless, glad you got your data back.